# How can I change the Android launch screen (ic launcher) background

Tags: android, capacitor

I can't find a simple solution to change the white background to a custom color. I've been watching videos but nothing works for me. My ic_launcher icon is fine. I just want to change the background from white to a custom color. Thans for your help

PS: I'm using Capacitor for a hybrid app

Tried to modify some background value in ic launcher but doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I set the value in the styles for v31 and that did it.